# An iceFaces - facelets URL bar address is not showing

Tags: facelets, icefaces-1.8

My company has the *Spring-Ifaces* 1.8 standard to work with a IBM WAS 6.1 solution. After read the icefaces tutorials, i decide to implement a facelets solution to do a better template management.

In the faces-config.xml i put the next line to config the facelets:

```
  <view-handler>com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
```

The web.xml is configured to search the index.jsp as the main page on the context:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The index forward to the first page on my navigation logic.

```
  <body>
    <jsp:forward page="paso1.iface" /> 
  </body>
```

But on the browser URL bar address, i still seeing the *http://server.com/context* path.

When the form data is already written, i submit, run my action and the navigation rule send me to the next page.

But again, on the browser URL bar address, is still in the *http://server.com/context* path.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/step1.jspx</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{actionBean.action}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/step2.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{actionBean.action}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/step1.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I can't use redirect, because there is some session data. And even i try using the standard Java EE Facelets tag *com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler*, but the page can't be rendered.

How can I force or config properly the IceFaces Facelet to show me the webpage than I'm already step on?

--- web.xml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>venta-directa-web</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.component.inputfile.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.SimpleCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>width</param-name>
            <param-value>250</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>height</param-name>
            <param-value>75</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ChineseCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.ChineseCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>width</param-name>
            <param-value>265</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>height</param-name>
            <param-value>50</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.actionURLSuffix</param-name>
        <param-value>.iface</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.debugDOMUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.delegateNonIface</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatRetries</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.standardRequestScope</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.component.OutputTextTag</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>upload</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>La cantidad en bytes de un archivo a subir por icefaces.</description>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>4048576</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:app-web-context.xml
            classpath:app-core-context.xml
            classpath:app-ws-context.xml
            classpath:app-dao-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mainservlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/uploadHtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/simpleImg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/stickyImg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ChineseCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/chineseImg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/checkService.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

--- faces-config.xml app config ---

```
<application>
    <view-handler>com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>

    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>es</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

Hope somebody had an answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ugly solution, but work for me. Is about override the Viewandler:
http://www.logikdev.com/2010/03/24/how-to-personalise-the-urls-with-faces-navigation/